# Convert tick data to candlestick (OHLC) with MS localdb

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been trying to follow this solution ( [Convert tick data to candlestick (OHLC) with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58795220/convert-tick-data-to-candlestick-ohlc-with-sql) ) to fit my needs for my home project which has SQL Server Express Localdb as database. My SQL knowledge is a bit unsharp so hoping for help :-)

I have a price, a float (53), (e.g. value 109,2) and a time, a datetime, (e.g. value 2021-02-11 21:26:45.000)

I need to get candlesticks per minute.

Then I have this T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
    t1.price as open,
    m.high,
    m.low,
    t2.price as close,
    open_time
FROM
    (SELECT 
         MIN(Publication_time) AS min_time,
         MAX(Publication_time) AS max_time,
         MIN(price) AS low,
         MAX(price) AS high,
         FLOOR((CAST(DATEDIFF(s, Publication_time, GETUTCDATE()) AS BIGINT) * 1000) / (1000 * 60)) AS open_time          
      FROM 
          stocks
      GROUP BY 
          open_time) m
JOIN 
    stocks t1 ON t1.Publication_time = min_time
JOIN 
    stocks t2 ON t2.Publication_time = max_time
```

It is parsed alright, but I get an error

> Invalid column name 'open_time'

on execution. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Tried m.open_time but again it says : Invalid column name 'open_time'.

Comment: Have you mistyped the column name in the inner query, by chance??

Comment: I checked the use of open_time but could not find any type error. The error is in line 12 where it states : GROUP BY open_time) m

Comment: ah okay - yeah, you *cannot* use the named of a "computed" column in the `group by` at the same level ... you'll need to repeat the whole expression in the `group by` clause

Comment: That worked. I replaced open_time after group by with FLOOR((CAST(Datediff(s,Publication_time, GETUTCDATE()) AS BIGINT)*1000)/(1000*60)) and get lots of lines . I added a where clause that filters the stock name. The prices are unfortunately wrong. Here is an example open high low close open_time 2814 319,9 319,9 12760 32218 the low or high or both could be correct but why do i get open and close prices that differ a lot from high low?

Comment: @tvviewer if you aren't obtaining the results you require you need to open a new question (since this one is specific to solving the error), and provide sample data as DDL+DML and expected results.

Comment: I am considering opening a new question, but i am not ready. I think i managed to filter by stockname and that gives at least some data that looks right. However, in highcharts (stockchart) which i use for testing the data, i need to order by open_time descending. How to do that in the sql above?

Answer (score 0):

A common way to avoid repeating the same calculation is to calculate it in a `cross apply` e.g.

```
SELECT 
    MIN(Publication_time) AS min_time
    , MAX(Publication_time) AS max_time
    , MIN(price) AS low
    , MAX(price) AS high
    , C.open_time          
FROM stocks S
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (FLOOR((CAST(DATEDIFF(s, Publication_time, GETUTCDATE()) AS BIGINT) * 1000) / (1000 * 60)))) AS C (open_time)
GROUP BY C.open_time
```

A sub-query will also accomplish the same thing, but isn't as neat (IMO).